# JQuery Adjusting Margin-Left based on Pixel Adjusted Percentage Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a floating table that I'm trying to position off the right side of the visible screen than when you click on the icon it animates in from the right.

I can't set the margin-left by percentages since my resolution is different from other people and it wouldn't work correctly. So I am trying to adjust the margin-left from the side by the icon's width in a sort of negative offset.

I have tried setting the margin-left = 100% and then '-=56px' but that's not working.

Here's what I've got JQuery wise

```
//This does not work correctly so i have it set the margin-left inline at 88% that works just for me
//$('#quick-notes-quick-menu-icon').css('margin-left', '100%');
//$('#quick-notes-quick-menu-icon').css('margin-left', '-=56px');


$('#quick-notes-quick-menu-icon').click(function(){
    if($('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle').is(":visible") == false)
    {
        $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-icon').fadeOut(200);

        $('#quick-notes-quick-menu').animate({
            marginLeft: '60%'   
        }, 500);

        $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle').toggle('slow');
        $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle-btn').toggle('slow');
    }
});

$('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle-btn').click(function(){
    $('#quick-notes-quick-menu').animate({
            marginLeft: '100%'  
        }, 500);

    $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle').toggle('slow');
    $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle-btn').toggle('slow');

    $('#quick-notes-quick-menu-icon').fadeIn(200);
});
```

And Here's my Div **please note** it is relative positioned and has a z index as such to float it on top of the rest of the page.

```
<div id='quick-notes-div'>
            <img id='quick-notes-quick-menu-icon' src='../images/quick-notes-menu.png' style='position: fixed; z-index: 1000001;margin-left: 100%; margin-top: 20%;' />
// The margin is set inline here to work with my browser
            <table id='quick-notes-quick-menu' style='position: fixed; z-index: 1000001; margin-left: 88%; background: rgba(112,168,210,0.6); height: 80%'>
            <tr>
                <td style='padding-left: 10px; display: none;' id='quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle'>
                <button style='display: none;' id='quick-notes-quick-menu-toggle-btn' class='ui-state-focus'>x</button>";
// This just populates the rows n whatnot with info from a sql db
                <? include("quick-notes-quick-menu.inc"); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Imho, you'd be better served if you created a more focused question.  The best SO questions are ones that others may also find useful.  Try to recreate this without the PHP and stick it in a fiddle so others can tinker with it.  And while you're at it, learn to rewrite this without tables and inline styles. ;)

Comment: That makes sense, I tried to reduce code down to the bare minimum needed n whatnot. I'll trim it some more and separate the questions so it's more focused on the individual issues I'm seeing / maybe re-word. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late-ish update:

I was able to get this to work. I was putting this inside a div inside another div which is where the issue was occuring. The Negative Offset was being based on the div's width/position. I went up a few div levels to give it a position on the whole page instead of limiting it to one div, I used the z-index to float it above and was able to place it with the margin offsets (since they where the page's margins instead of the div's).